# How to get the API request response via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, flickr

I'm trying to get the API response of Flickr via Ajax in my application. I'm using Laravel. I have a specific Route and a function to make the API calls.

```
//Route.php
Route::post('/getlocation/{latitude}/{longitude}', ['as'=>'get-location', 'uses'=>'FormController@getLocationImage']);
```

and the function

```
//getLocationImage()

//GET THE IMAGES BASED ON THE LOCATION FROM FLICKR.
            $api_key = 'my_api_key_is_here';
            $tag = 'night,sunset,sunrise,park,people,summer,tree,flowers';
            $lat = '&lat='.$latitude;
            $lon = '&lon='.$longitude;
            $perPage = 12;
            $url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
            $url.= '&api_key='.$api_key;
            $url.= '&tags='.$tag;
            $url.= $lat;
            $url.= $lon;
            $url.= '&per_page='.$perPage;
            $url.= '&format=json';
            $url.= '&nojsoncallback=1';

            $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
            $photo_array = $response->photos->photo;
            return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "photo_array"=>$photo_array]);
```

Now In a jquery function, I'm calling the Ajax.

```
$("#nomination-name").focus(function(){
        $.post(
            '/getlocation/'+$("#newLatitude").val()+"/"+$("#newLongitude").val(), // location of your php script
            { user: "bob", id: 1234 }, // any data you want to send to the script
            function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information

                alert(data);

            });
    });
```

But when I try to alert the data, it just shows `[object Object]` 
How can I get the response back in the Ajax call?
Output from the console is given below.

```
Object 
photo_array: Array[12]
0: Objectfarm: 8
id: "16325992992"
isfamily: 0
isfriend: 0
ispublic: 1
owner: "35736862@N03"
secret: "b7044c5b46"
server: "7548"
title: "#snow #trees #winter #parcangrignon #montreal #livemontreal #themainmtl #mtlblog #vscocam"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
..............
```

Comment: Try console.log(data) instead of alert, or just do alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: So, in other words, you're getting data, but just don't know how to use it. `[object Object]` is the string representation of an object, and you should be expecting an object from your response, so, you're obviously getting a response.

Comment: @KevinB: Well, thats true. I'm just learning Ajax.

Comment: @juvian: How an I get a specific array element and add it to a <div> ?

Comment: if you want to add it as text, $('#yourDiv').append(arrText[3])

Comment: @juvian: what is that `arrText` ?

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve with this code, do you simply want to place the JSON string into a div or get images from it?

Comment: @MJPinfield get images from it.

Comment: arrText is your array

Comment: in which case you don't want it as a string you need it as an object, can you post sample response, then either I or someone else can help you

Comment: @juvian: This is the response from the console.log(data) output.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/tweVD.png I just want to add all these images in a div <div id="images"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve shouldn't be to hard. I cannot see the contents of photo_array but as long as you know how to iterate through an object you will be fine.

```
for(i=0;i<data.images.length;i++) {
    $("#images").append(data.images[i])
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="images"></div>
```

Here's the code you need, `photo_array` may not look the same but it shouldn't cause an issue just iterate through it. [Here's](http://codepen.io/MaxJP/pen/MYmZzj?editors=101) the link to my test.

Comment: This is the response from the console.log(data) output.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/tweVD.png I just want to add all these images in a div <div id="images"></div>